# Appending to a String in a loop and retain access to the appended String

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to append to a `String` inside a `for` loop. After it iterates I access the `String` for use but it's still empty. Why is it still empty?

Code:

```
String message = "";
for(int i = 1; i==args.length; i+=1){
    message+=" "+args[i];
}
```

I'm developing a plugin for Bukkit (and the `args` are from Bukkit)

Comment: Did you mean to write `i<=args.length` in the for loop? Right now, the for loop isn't running at all unless `args.length` is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, first the second parameter in your `for` loop should be something like

```
String message = "";
for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i+=1){
    message+=" "+args[i];
}
```

But, arrays start at `0` and you can use `++` so I think you really wanted

```
String message = "";
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
    message+=" "+args[i];
}
```

Then, you might prefer the simpler [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
String message = "";
for(String arg : args){
    message+=" "+arg;
}
```

Finally, I would really prefer you use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (to avoid creating so many temporary `String`s) like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String arg : args){
    sb.append(" ").append(arg);
}
String message = sb.toString();
```